# Python: Web Scraping Tag Navigation wiki table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to isolate just the 'Career History' -list of the teams a player has played - section of the table on NFL Qbs using bs4 :

my desired output is:

```
['St. Louis Rams (2005–2006)', 'Cincinnati Bengals (2007–2008)', 'Buffalo Bills (2009–2012)', 'Tennessee Titans (2013)', 'Houston Texans (2014)', 'New York Jets (2015–2016)', 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers (2017–2018)', 'Miami Dolphins (2019–present)']
```

my code is:

```
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryan_Fitzpatrick'
table = BeautifulSoup(player_wiki.text , 'html.parser')

for tr  in table.find('tbody').find_all('ul'):
  v = [li.text for li in tr.find_all('li')]
  print(v)
```

current output:

```
['St. Louis Rams (2005–2006)', 'Cincinnati Bengals (2007–2008)', 'Buffalo Bills (2009–2012)', 'Tennessee Titans (2013)', 'Houston Texans (2014)', 'New York Jets (2015–2016)', 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers (2017–2018)', 'Miami Dolphins (2019–present)']
['Ivy League Player of the Year (2004)', 'First-team All–Ivy League (2004)', 'George H. “Bulger” Lowe Award (2004)']
```

i am sure it's my outer loop's 'ul' tag. How can a narrow the scope of my find_all() to prevent unwanted data? any tips? I am new to web scraping.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/wikitextparser/

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/Wikipedia-API/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `soup.find_all`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryan_Fitzpatrick').text, 'html.parser')
result = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in d.find('table', {'class':'infobox vcard'}).find_all('tr')[12].find_all('li')]
```

Output:

```
['St. Louis Rams(2005–2006)', 'Cincinnati Bengals(2007–2008)', 'Buffalo Bills(2009–2012)', 'Tennessee Titans(2013)', 'Houston Texans(2014)', 'New York Jets(2015–2016)', 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers(2017–2018)', 'Miami Dolphins(2019–present)']
```

Answer (score 2):

Approach 1 - Using [requests](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/) and [beautifulsoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```py
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryan_Fitzpatrick')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    for item in soup.find('tbody').findAll('ul'):
        for href in item.findAll('a'):
            print(href.get_text())
```

Approach 2- Using [wikipedia](https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia) module:

```py
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import wikipedia

    ry = wikipedia.page('Ryan_Fitzpatrick')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(ry.html(), 'html.parser')
    career_history = []
    for tr in soup.find('tbody').find_all('ul'):
        for li in tr.find_all('li'):
          career_history.append(li.text)

    print(career_history)
```

output:

```
['St. Louis Rams (2005–2006)', 'Cincinnati Bengals (2007–2008)', 'Buffalo Bills (2009–2012)', 'Tennessee Titans (2013)', 'Houston Texans (2014)', 'New York Jets (2015–2016)', 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers (2017–2018)', 'Miami Dolphins (2019–present)', 'Ivy League Player of the Year (2004)', 'First-team All–Ivy League (2004)', 'George H. “Bulger” LoweAward (2004)']
```